# Pretty URLs routing issue

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, .htaccess

I have an problem with pretty urls routing in angular js. I fixed the pretty url issue enabling html5mode true and changing the base href.
Example:

Base href :

For accessing the angular site

Main Url : http://localhost/creatcod/cod_angular/

When navigating to services it works fine.

Services Url : http://localhost/creatcod/cod_angular/services/

But when I move into its services detail page

Detail Service Url : http://localhost/creatcod/cod_angular/services/5

The problem arises :(

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
http://localhost/createcod/cod_angular/services/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

The problem is base url changes by adding services. So, bootstrap css file is not found and creating this issue

Htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On  
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /createcod/cod_angular/index.html
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: use `<base>` tag or absolute paths for resources

Comment: @charlietfl can you provide me any example in angular js ??  for solving that

Comment: can put a leading `/` in front of script and css src/href ... makes them absolute and browser will start at root of site or root of href set in base tag

Comment: adding a leading "/" doesnt take base href  (<base href="/createcod/cod_angular/">)

Comment: right...should say "or use" base tag

Comment: Didnt use <base> tag but i found that i was using <base href="/createcod/cod_angular/"> just below my one css link :) thanks buddy